# How does selling a stock short affect my cash and margin positions in my account?

Tags: investing, shorting-securities

Example of my etrade account: I have $3k cash and $0 margin debt and my account net balance shows $50k.  I then sell to open a $4k position in XYZ how does this impact the cash, margin and net balance?

Answer (score 2):

The FRB's RegT requires 150% of the value of the short sale.  So if you short $4k of stock XYZ then you need $2k of cash in order to execute the trade.  This is a more complicated way of saying that you need 50% of the value of the short position to open it.  Brokers have the right to require a higher amount of margin.

The minimum required level of margin for the position is 25%.  Again, brokers have the right to require a higher amount of margin.  If you only had $2k in the account then for your short position, the minimum margin maintenance level would be $4,800.

With $3k in the account then you have additional buffer.  Whether the remaining  $47k of equity is marginable depends on what that equity is from (options with less than 9 months remaining until expiration and stocks under $5 are not marginable).

Comment: im still confused... as far as the  values of the 3 parameters i gave, what would  be their values on the monthly  statement after this short.. it  seems that my $3k  cash is showing  as 0 and im also  showing $1k addiotional in margin debt. this equals the $4k i needed to 'borrow' the shares im selling to open. my   account shows $4k more as a line item ? but the 'net account value'  seems to take the $50k +  $4k - $3k (cash) - $1k (margin debt) =  $50k of actual net value.   am i misreading this? thx

Comment: I don't know how  E*Trade's statement appears since I don't use them. The short answer is that if you short $4k then your cash should increase + $4k and there should be a - $4k short equity offset.   You should see an increase of $4k cash from the short proceeds and a line item depicting the position as minus  "X" shares or an "S" for short or something similar with  a negative value of $4k to represent the unchanged cost of buying the short position to close.  Either way, your account value should be $50k.

Comment: thank you Bob. an add on Q for clarity...during the period that i  am holding the short position (ie before I close it and take a gain or loss), am i being margin debt?

Comment: If you have $3k of cash in the account and you have shorted $4k of stock then you have a margin position of $1k.  If not already aware of it, you will be charged an annual percent  borrow fee which varies as well as being liable for  dividends if you are short on the ex-dividend date.

Comment: thanks. im trying to understand the logic of it. in this case, I "borrow" the $4k of stock and have to pay that amount for it. thus they take my $3k cash and give me 1k of margin debt? effectively am i "buying/paying for"  the stock even though im shorting it.   while I have the position open, if the stock goes up... does my margin debt increase or was it only based on the price when i opened the position. while  my position  is open, my $3k of cash is gone?  thx

Comment: You have $3k in your account.  You borrow 100 shares that is trading at $40.  You sell it and $4k is credited to your account (you don't pay for the stock).   You now have $7k cash in your account with a short stock position with a debit of -$4k (I don't know how E*Trade denotes this).  If the stock goes up, the debit value of the short position increases.  At $50, you have $7k of cash and a -$5k debit on the short position (you're down $1k).  If you bought the stock back for $5k you would have $2k of cash remaining.  You would own borrow fees for the time you had the short position.

Comment: Would someone kindly give me the Cliff Notes version of how I can set up a Private Chat with Cool Pontiac so we don't do the extended discussion no-no?  TIA

Comment: Bob - i appreciate your patience and detailed answers. I think  comments are valuable part of this experience so others can see the info too, no?